# SQL Server Select with two IN clause in conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join

I'm stuck in writing a query. It's a simple query, but I have some doubts. So I want some new approaches on the task

```
DECLARE @ordersToSet TABLE 
                     (
                         [Id] [BIGINT] NOT NULL,
                         [AttributeId] [BIGINT] NOT NULL
                     )

SELECT * 
FROM dbo.Order_Attributes
WHERE OrderAttributeID IN (SELECT AttributeId
                           FROM @ordersToSet) 
  AND OrderID IN (SELECT Id
                  FROM @ordersToSet)
```

What I want: the query should return only those `Order_Attributes` where both `OrderId` and `AttributeId` match the respective values in temp table `@ordersToSet`.

Why I think the above code could lead to unexpected results:

`@ordersToSet` table has the following rows

```
    Id     | AttributeId
    -------+------------
    486455 | 12
```

`OrderAttributes` table has the following:

```
    OrderID | OrderAttributeID
    --------+-----------------
    486455  | 11
    635201  | 12
```

In this case it should NOT select any row, however I doubt it selects A ROW with values `OrderId = 486455` and `AttributeId = 12`

Comment: Where is your FROM? ...but, yes, you're right, that approach would get undesired results even when that is corrected; you should simply just go with a JOIN on both fields.

Comment: Your code won't run.

Comment: @Uueerdo I forgot to add "FROM". Now fixed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The query should return only those `Order_Attributes` where both `OrderId` and `AttributeId` match the respective values in temp table `@ordersToSet`.

You seem to be looking for a simple `JOIN`:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM dbo.Order_Attributes a 
INNER JOIN @ordersToSet s
    ON a.OrderAttributeID = s.AttributeId AND a.OrderID = s.Id
```

Comment: I think you mean the following: 
SELECT a.*
 FROM dbo.Order_Attributes a 
 INNER JOIN @ordersToSet s on s.AttributeId = a.OrderAttributeID AND a.OrderID = s.Id

Comment: @DavronbekRahmonov: yes indeed. Fixed.

Comment: Welcome @DavronbekRahmonov!